# MySQL sorting by max child date

Tags: mysql, performance, nested-sets

I have a table with nested children.  I'm trying to fetch a list of parents sorted by the most recent child, when available, otherwise the parent's created date.  My query seemed to work at first, but as I started importing more and more records (@13.6K atm), performance has become a problem.

Version: `10.5.5-MariaDB`

Table structure (excluded fields for brevity):

```
CREATE TABLE `emails` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `_lft` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `_rgt` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `emails__lft__rgt_parent_id_index` (`_lft`,`_rgt`,`parent_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `emails__lft__rgt_created_at_index` (`_lft`,`_rgt`,`created_at`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13484 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here's the query I'm working with (@21s):

```
SELECT
    `emails`.`id`,
    (
        SELECT  MAX(`descendants`.`created_at`) AS `created_at`
        FROM `emails` AS `descendants`
        WHERE `descendants`.`_lft` >= `emails`.`_lft`
        AND `descendants`.`_rgt` <= `emails`.`_rgt`
    ) `descendants_created_at`
FROM `emails`
WHERE `parent_id` IS NULL
ORDER BY `descendants_created_at` DESC
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```

The `_lft` and `_rgt` fields are provided by the [lazychaser/laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) package and are essentially giving me the descendants for each of the records returned in the main query.  It includes the parent as well, so a created_at value is always returned.

Sample output:

```
| id    | created_at          | descendants_created_at |
|-------|---------------------|------------------------|
| 13483 | 2021-07-22 12:35:55 | 2021-07-22 12:35:55    |
|  8460 | 2021-04-29 12:56:57 | 2021-07-22 12:35:00    |
| 13481 | 2021-07-22 12:33:22 | 2021-07-22 12:33:22    |
|  3514 | 2021-01-16 09:43:42 | 2021-07-22 12:23:28    |
| 13479 | 2021-07-22 11:28:07 | 2021-07-22 11:28:07    |
| 13478 | 2021-07-22 11:27:09 | 2021-07-22 11:27:09    |
| 13407 | 2021-07-21 10:05:41 | 2021-07-22 10:21:14    |
| 13408 | 2021-07-21 10:05:41 | 2021-07-22 10:21:14    |
| 13389 | 2021-07-21 08:17:23 | 2021-07-22 10:21:14    |
| 13303 | 2021-07-19 14:25:38 | 2021-07-22 10:21:14    |
```

The problem seems to be once I'm doing the actual ordering here:

```
ORDER BY `descendants_created_at` DESC
```

My EXPLAIN looks like this:
[image]

UPDATE #1 - Using a LEFT JOIN & adding a parent_id key, this query is now @10s which is better, but still not great:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=f5442fdfba119cc750c09a19024ccf7c

Comment: Post a sample data and table structure, current output and expected output. Also, what is your MySQL version, please run `SELECT version();` to check.

Comment: Updated.  The output shown is correct, however, the performance isn't acceptable.  Performance will get worse the more records that are added to the table.

Comment: What are the values in `_lft` and `_rgt` columns? You could try to do `JOIN` instead of doing correlated sub-query in `SELECT`. And try adding an index on `parent_id`. That may improve the performance.

Comment: [See this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=bafb5468e1fc5026c1fad1d00a9a2891), there's a slight difference with the query `EXPLAIN` when adding a single index on `parent_id`.

Comment: `_lft` and `_rgt` are integer fields that keep track of the descendants.  For example, in the result set id #8460 has a created_at date of 4/29 but the latest descendant has a date of 7/22.  That's because it has 4 descendants.

8460 has a `_lft` value of 17586 and a `_rgt` value of 17593.  Each descendant record is between the _lft and _rgt values.  17586, 17587-17588, 17589-17590, 17591-17592.  This is part of the package I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I added a fiddle (Update #1 in the question) with a LEFT JOIN & `parent_id` index.  It reduced it to @10 seconds which is better, but still not great and will likely have scaling issues.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I guess, since your `ON` condition is doing a "equal or bigger/smaller than", without any fixed relation, it's always going to be tricky to get great performance.

Comment: Can you add some sample data in the fiddle and post it here. That may gave us some general idea on the data source and maybe can give some alternative query ideas on how to achieve your expected result more efficiently.

Comment: I revised my fiddle to include some data.  The performance issue increased the more records are in the table.

Comment: Based on my checking here is what I discovered, regardless of `_lft` and `_rgt` value I found that your desired output is similar with a hierarchical link through `id` and `parent_id`. If this is accurate, I assume constructing a query using that relation might be more efficient than doing `>=` or `<=`. I'm eager to test this theory and see the results but unfortunately I'm a bit busy right now so I just post this comment first and maybe give you some alternative ideas.